# Creating view with json (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm facing several issues.

I want to deserialize my json to create Views.

I want to create view, so I created a json model who describe my page with several views in it. I have created classes who's going to create my views. Before the json I was doing this in static:

```
ElementModel element = new ElementModel();
element.Width = 100;
element.Height = 40;
element.Top = 0;
element.Left = 0;
element.Label = "Element num 1";
element.IsEnabled = true;
element.IsMandatory = false;

ElementView ev1 = new TextBoxView(element);
al.Children.Add(ev3.getView());
this.Content = new ScrollView { Content = al };
```

And it worked fine, this code above was creating an Entry view placed with top, left informations and the width, height dimensions in the json.

---

I wanted something more dynamic so I created a json, I deserialize it and after that I create my views.

```
ScrollView sv;
RelativeLayout rl;
AbsoluteLayout al;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        al = new AbsoluteLayout();
        testDeserialize();

        //I was creating view with this function before
        //testView();

    }

    public void testDeserialize()
    {
        string json = @"myjson in the link";


        string newjson = json.Replace("'", "\'");
        TourApplication ta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TourApplication>(newjson);

        models.Page p = ta.Pages.ElementAt(0);

        ElementView ev=null;
        foreach (ElementModel em in p.Elments)
        {
            //ev = new TextBoxView(em); 
            //al.Children.Add(ev.getView()); doesn't work
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------"+em.Label); 
        }

        this.Content = new ScrollView { Content = al };
    }
```

The creation doesn't work but I'm doing the same operation when it was working. 
I have no idea what I can do to fix this. 
You can find in this [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g9lvtp) the json with the generated class structure.

Thx for your help.

> EDIT : The problem was due to my json, now I can have my Views. But only one of my View is editable. I mean for the others the keyboard doesn't show.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you are requesting any height or widths for the elements you add. Nor have you requested any for your `ScrollView`

Comment: @Cheesebaron thx, it was that. It's wroten in french, so height = hauteur and width = largeur. And it's not a json written by myself. So I trusted the guy who done this. I didn't expect that. THX